# Paste vector to expression in x label

Tags: r

I am trying to create second line of `x label` in `ggplot`. A vector containing letters need to be printed there.

```
DF
line 1   line 2
A          1
B          1
C          2
D          2
```

I found that second line of labels could be added with

```
xlab = expression(atop(paste("line 1"),
            "line 2"))
```

But obviously it prints only "line 1" and "line 2". Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: it results in `DF$line1` in the first line and `DF$line2` in the second, but not with data containing there

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at mtext

```
mtext(c(paste(DF[,1], collapse=' '), paste(DF[,2], collapse=' ')), line=2:1)
```

EDIT:
This produced what you want, or?

```
x <- runif(n=10)
lt <- data.frame(line1=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), line2=rep(1:2, each=2))
plot(x)
mtext(c(paste(lt$line1, collapse=' '), paste(lt$line2, collapse=' ')), line=2:1)
```

EDIT2:
Using ggplot2

```
df <- data.frame(gp = factor(rep(letters[1:3], each = 10)), y = rnorm(30))
library(ply)
ds <- ddply(df, .(gp), summarise, mean = mean(y), sd = sd(y))
plot.new()
ggplot(df, aes(x = gp, y = y)) + geom_point() + geom_point(data = ds, aes(y = mean), colour = 'red', size = 3)
mtext(c('x', 'y'), line=1:2, side=2)
```

Comment: It just prints names of columns in 2 lines

Comment: No it prints: "A B C D" in the first line and "1 1 2 2" in the second. Or what do you want?

Comment: Nope, mtext is working with ggplot2, I just tried it. I will edit my post with using ggplot2. Maybe you should change the line parameter, because you are writing with mtext outside your plotting area. Sometimes it helps playing with some par() arguments.

Comment: when i run your code i get error `Error in mtext(c("x", "y"), line = 1:2, side = 2) :  plot.new has not been called yet`..

Comment: when i run your code i get error `Error in mtext(c("x", "y"), line = 1:2, side = 2) :  plot.new has not been called yet`.. I tried to run plot.new() prior your code but then it only prints YX in two lines..do you have any idea why? Thank you for help!

Comment: I edit my code, just call plot.new() prior ggplot call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111970/discussion-between-florianschunke-and-hohoho).